# Performance in Java through code?

Tags: java, performance, optimization

First of all I should mention that I'm aware of the fact that performance optimizations can be very project specific. I'm mostly not facing these special issues right now. I'm facing a bunch of performance issues with the JVM itself.

I wonder now:

- which code-optimization make sense
  from a compiler perspective: for
  example to support the garbage
  collector I declared variables as
  final - very much following PMD's
  suggestions here from Eclipse.
- what best practices there are for: vmargs,
  heap and other stuff passed to the
  JVM for initialization. How do I get
  the right values here? Is there any
  formula or is it try and error?

Java automates a lot, does many optimization on byte-code level and stuff. However I think most of that must be planed by a developer in order to work.

So how do you speed up your programs in Java? :)

Comment: declaring variables as finals does not help the compiler as much as it helps the unfamiliar maintainer.  You solemnly swear as the programmer that you _KNOW_ (and that the maintainer also should know) that this value is not changed in the code below.

Comment: hmh, okay. I thought it might help the GC.

Comment: What is “PMD”? Explain/link your abbreviations.

Comment: This Question seems too broad and open-ended for Stack Exchange. Voting to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see this a lot. The sequence generally goes:

1. Thinking performance is about compiler optimizations, big-O, and so on.
2. Designing software using the recommended ideas, lots of classes, two-way linked lists, trees with pointers up, down, left, and right, hash sets, dictionaries, properties that invoke other properties, event handlers that invoke other event handlers, XML writing, parsing, zipping and unzipping, etc. etc.
3. Since all those data structures were like O(1) and the compiler's optimizing its guts out, the app should be "efficient", right? Well, then, what's that little voice telling one that the startup is slow, the shutdown is slow, the loading and unloading could be faster, and why is the UI so sluggish?
4. Hand it off to the "performance expert". With luck, that person finds out, all this stuff is done in the recommended way, but that's why it's cranking its heart out. It's doing all that stuff because it's the recommended way to do things, *not because it's needed*.
5. With luck, one has the chance to re-engineer some of that stuff, to make it simple, and gradually remove the "bottlenecks". I say, "with luck" because often it's just not possible, so development relies on the next generation of faster processors to take away the pain.

This happens in every language, but moreso in Java, C#, C++, where abstraction has been carried to extremes. So by all means, be aware of best practices, but also understand what *simple software* is. Typically it consists of saving those best practices for the circumstances that really need them.

Comment: +1 because you neither aren't drinking the Java Cool Aid [TM].

Comment: Best practices don't necessarily encourage unperformant code.

Comment: @Jay: Necessarily - no. Typically - yes. It takes a really seasoned programmer not to over-use them. That's why I said "saving those best practices for the circumstances that really need them". Hey - I used to do the same thing, until I learned something about performance - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773

Answer (score 6):

> Which code-optimization make sense from a compiler perspective: for example to support the garbage collector I declared variables as final - very much following PMD's suggestions here from Eclipse.

Assuming you are talking about potential micro-optimizations you can make to your code, the answer is pretty much none.   The best way to increase your application performance is to run a profiler to figure out where the performance bottlenecks are, then figure out if there is anything you can do to speed them up.

All of the classic tricks like declaring classes, variables and methods final, reorganizing loops, changing primitive types are pretty much a waste of effort in most cases.  The JIT compiler can typically do a much better job than you can.  For example, recent JIT compilers will analyse all loaded classes to figure out which method calls are not subject to overloading, without you declaring the classes or methods as `final`.  It will then use a quicker call sequence, or even inline the method body.

Indeed, the Sun experts say that some programmer attempts at optimization fail because they actually make it harder for JIT compiler to apply the optimizations it knows about.

On the other hand, higher level algorithmic optimizations are definitely worthwhile ... provided that your profiler tells you that your application is spending a significant amount of time in that area of the code.

Using arrays instead of collections can be a worthwhile optimization in unusual cases, and in rare cases using object pools might be too.  But these optimizations 1) will make your code more complicated and bug prone and 2) can slow your application down if used inappropriately.  These kinds of optimizations should only be tried as a last resort.  For example, if your profiling says that such and such a `HashMap<Integer,Integer>` is a CPU bottleneck or a memory hog, then it is a better idea to look for an existing specialized `Map` or `Map`-like library class than to try and implement the map yourself using arrays.  In other words, optimize at the high level.

If you spend long enough or your application is small enough, careful micro-optimization will probably give you a faster application (on a given JVM version / hardware platform) than just relying on the JIT compiler.  If you are implementing a smallish application to do large-scale number crunching in Java, the pay-off of micro-optimization may well be considerable.  But this is clearly not a typical case!  For typical Java applications, the effort is large enough and the performance difference is small enough that micro-optimization is not worthwhile.

(Incidentally, I don't see how declaring a variable can make any possible difference to GC performance.  The GC has to trace a variable every time it is encountered whether or not it is final.  Besides, it is an open secret that final variables can actually change under certain circumstances, so it would be unsafe for the GC to assume that they don't.  Unsafe as in "creates a dangling pointer resulting in a JVM crash".)

Comment: According to Joshua Bloch (Effective Java) and Brian Goetz (Java Concurrency In Practice) declaring member variables as final is almost always a good idea (though mostly for reasons of keeping parts of the state of the object immutable). And while it often may not be a good idea, using arrays directly can make a huge difference. P.S.: I upvoted your post, as most of your points are valid.

Comment: Yes - declaring variables as `final` **is** a good idea.  But for reasons that have **nothing to do with performance**.  If `javac` can figure out that it is legal to declare `someVar` as `final`, the JIT compiler can also figure out that `someVar` *could have been* declared as final ... and optimize accordingly.

Comment: Shadowing an array reference can be done almost completely transparent by using the same identifier: final [TYPE] myArrayRef = this.myArrayRef. If there is any place where the local shadow needs to be copied back to the instance, the compiler will complain at those places. I expect that this kind of code invariant movement will be done by the JIT some day (Java 6/7 seem to little, if any at all, invariant movement currently).

Comment: I initially downvoted because the answer was too simplistic.. i.e. "computer says no". I like your edited answer and have since upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

> which code-optimization make sense
>   from a compiler perspective?

All the ones that a compiler can't reason about, because a compiler is very dumb and Java doesn't have "design by contract" (which, hence, cannot help the dumb compiler reason about your code).

For example if you're crunching data and using use int[] or long[] arrays, you may know something about your data that is **IMPOSSIBLE** for the compiler to figure out and you may use low-level bit-packing/compacting to improve the locality of reference in that part of your code.

Been there, done that, saw gigantic speedup.  So much for the "super smart compiler".

This is just one example. There are a huge number of cases like this.

Remember that a compiler is *really* stupid: it cannot know that *if ( Math.abs(42) > 0 )* will always return true.

This should give some food for thoughts to people that think that those compilers are "smart" (things would be different here if Java had DbC, but it doesn't).

> what best practices there are for:
>   vmargs, heap and other stuff passed to
>   the JVM for initialization. How do I
>   get the right values here? Is there
>   any formula or is it try and error?

The real answer is: there shouldn't be. Sadly the situation is so pathetic that such low-level hackery is needed, due to serious failure on Java's part. Oh, one more "tiny" detail: playing with VM fine-tuning only works for server-side app. It doesn't work for desktop apps.

Anyone who has worked on Java desktop applications installed on hundreds or thousands of machines, on various OSes knows all too well what *the* issue is: full GC pauses making your app look like it's broken.  The Apple VM on OS X 10.4 comes to mind for it's particularly afwul, but **ALL** the JVMs are subject to that issue.

What is worse: it is impossible to "fine tune" the GC's parameters across different OSes / VMs / memory configuration when your application is going to be run on hundreds/thousands of different configuration.

Anyone disputing that: please tell me how you "fine tune" your app knowing that it is going to be run both on octo-cores Mac loaded with 20 GB of ram (I've got users with such setups) and old OS X 10.4 PowerBook that have 768 MB of ram. Please?

But it is not bad: you should not, in the first place, have to be concerned with super-low-level detail like GC "fine tuning". The very fact that this is hinted to is a testimony to one area where Java has a major issue.

Java fans will keep on saying *"the GC is super fast, object creation is cheap"* while this is blatantly wrong. There's a reason with Trove' TIntIntHashMap runs around circles an HashMap<Integer,Integer>.

There's also a reason why at every new JVM release you'll get countless release notes explaining why *-XXGCHyperSteroidMultiTopNotch* offers better performance than the last "big JVM param" that every cool Java programmer had to know: maybe the JVM wasn't *that* great at GC'ing after all.

So to answer your question: how do you speed up Java programs? Easy, do like what the Trove guys did: stop needlessly creating gigantic amount of objects and stop needlessly auto(un)boxing primitives because they **will** kill your app's perfs.

A TIntIntHashMap **OWNS** the default HashMap<Integer,Integer> for a reason: for the same reason my apps are now **much** faster than before.

I stopped believing in crap like *"object creation costs nothing"* and *"the GC is super-optimized, don't worry about it"*.

I'm using Java to crunch data (I know, I'm a bit crazy) and the one thing that made my app faster was to stop believing all the propaganda surrounding the "cheap object creation" and "amazingly fast GC".

The truth is: **INSTEAD OF TRYING TO FINE-TUNE YOUR GC SETTINGS, STOP CREATING THAT MUCH GARBAGE IN THE FIRST PLACE**. This can be stated this way: if changing the GC settings radically changes the way your app run, it may be time to wonder if all the needless junk objects your creating are really needed.

Oh, you know what, I'm betting we'll see more and more release notes explaining why Java version x.y.z's GC is faster than version x.y.z-1's GC ;)

Comment: ++ for realism and passion. I see so much code that goes around making and letting go of things on the assumption that it's "cheap".

Comment: *"Remember that a compiler is really stupid: it cannot know that if ( Math.abs(42) > 0 ) will always return true."* - actually it COULD know that.  It probably doesn't because the cost/benefit analysis for trying a generalized version of this optimization across an entire application is poor.

Answer (score 2):

Generally there are two kinds of performance optimizations you need to do with Java:

- Algorithmic optimization.  Choose an algorithm which behaves like you need to.  For instance, a simple algorithm may perform best for small datasets, but the overhead of preparing a smarter algorithm may first pay off for much larger datasets.
- Bottleneck identification.  Here you need to be familiar with a profiler that can tell you what the problem is (humans always guess wrong) - memory leak?, slow method? etc...  A good one to start with is VisualVM which can attach to a running program, and is available in the latest Sun JDK.  When you know the problem, you can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer this too thoroughly because you haven't even mentioned what sort of project you're talking about.  Is it a desktop application?  A server-side application?

Desktop applications favor application startup time, so the HotSpot client VM is a good start.  Client applications don't necessarily need all of their heap space all the time, so a good balance between starting heap and max heap is useful.  (Like, maybe -Xms128m -Xmx512m)

Server applications favor overall throughput, which is something the HotSpot server VM is tuned for.  You should always allocate the min and max heap sizes the same on a server application.  There is an added cost at the system level to it having to malloc() and free() during garbage collection.  Use something like -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m.

There are several different garbage collectors also, which are tuned to different application types.

Take a read through the [Java SE 6 Performance White Paper](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/6performance.html) if you want more info on the garbage collector and other performance related items from Java 6.

Answer (score 1):

Todays JVM's are surprisingly robust when it comes to performance. Any microoptimizations you can apply will, in practically all cases, have only very minor impact on performance. This is easy to understand if you take a look on how typical language constructs (e.g. FOR vs WHILE) translate to bytecode - they are almost indistinguishable.
Making methods/variables final has absolutely no impact on performance on a decent JIT'd JVM. The JIT will keep track of which methods are really polymorphic and optimize away the dynamic dispatch where possible. Static methods can still be faster, since they don't have a this-reference = one less local variable (which at the same time, limits their application). Most efficient micro optimizations are not so much Java specific, for example code with lots of conditional statements can become very slow due to branch mispredictions by the processor. Sometimes conditionals can be replaced by other, sequential code flow constructs (often at the cost of readability), reducing the number of mispredicted branches (and this applies to all languages that somehow compile to native code).

Note that profilers tend to inflate the time spent in short, frequently called methods. This is due to the fact that profilers need to instrument the code to keep track of invocations - this can interfere with the JIT's ability to inline those methods (and the instrumentation overhead becomes significantly larger than the time spent actually executing the methods body). Manual inlining, while apparently very performance boosting under a profiler has in most cases no effect under "real world" conditions. Don't rely purely on the profilers results, verify that optimizations you make have real impact under real runtime conditions, too.

Notable performance boosts can only be expected from changes that reduce the amount of work done, more cache friendly data layout or superior algorytms. Java partially limits your possibilities for cache friendly data layouts, since you have no control where the parts (arrays/objects) that form your data structure will be located in memory in relation to each other. Still, there are plenty of opportunities where choosing the right data structure for the job can make a huge difference (e.g. ArrayList vs LinkedList).

There is little you can do to aid the garbage collector. However, a point worth noting is, while object allocation in Java is very very fast, there is still the cost of object initialization (which is mostly under your control). Poor performance of applications that creating lots of (short lived) objects is more likely to be attributed to poor cache utilization than to the garbage collectors work.

Different applications types require different optimization strategies - so before asking about specific optimizations, find out where your application really spends its time.

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing performance issues with your application, you should seriously consider trying some profiling (eg: hprof) to see whether the problem is algorithmic in nature, and also checking the GC performance logging (eg: -verbose:gc) to see if you could benefit from tuning your JVM GC options.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that the compiler does next to no optimisations, and the JVM doesn't optimise at the byte code level either.  Most of the optimisations are performed by the JIT in the JVM and it optmises how the code is converted to native machine code.

The best way to optimise your code is to use a profiler which measures how much time and resources your application is using when you give it a realistic data set.  Without this information you are just guessing and you can change alot of code where it really, really doesn't matter and find you have added bugs in the process.

Many come to the conclusion that its never worth optmising you code, even counter productive as it can waste time and introduce bugs and I would say that is true for 95+% of your code.  However, with aprofiler you can measure the critical pieces of code and optmise the <5% worth optimising and done carefully, you won't get too many issues from trying to optimise your code.